# Empty Count in Foreach Using Previous Result if Empty

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, count

Below are two MySql queries executed in Php.

On first glance they achieve what I want. It will count how many Users are in a Team, then count how often Locations appear and then group them, returning just the highest count for me to use as variable $flagcount.

However, if there are no Users and thus no Locations, it will return the result of the previous loop that did. When I run query this in PhpMyAdmin it returns no results / empty set.

I've tried NULLIF (as you can see, and location !='' as you can also see. For whatever reason, if its Empty/Null it will use the previous looped location count as its result.

```
 /** other table select --working loop-- */
 /** irrelevant code here  */

  foreach( $rows as $result ) {

    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT location, COUNT(NULLIF(TRIM(location), '')) as flagnum FROM users WHERE team_name='$teamname' AND location !='' GROUP BY location ORDER BY flagnum DESC LIMIT 1");
    $result->execute();
    $rows = $result->fetchAll();
    foreach( $rows as $result ):
    $flagmajority = $result['location'];
    $flagcount = $result['flagnum'];
    endforeach;

    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT team_name, COUNT(NULLIF(TRIM(team_name), '')) as playnum FROM users WHERE team_name='$teamname' AND team_name !='' GROUP BY team_name ORDER BY playnum DESC LIMIT 1");
    $result->execute();
    $rows = $result->fetchAll();
    foreach( $rows as $result ):
    $playercount = $result['playnum'];
    endforeach;


    $flagpercent = ($flagcount/$playercount) * 100;
    $roundedpercent = round($flagpercent);

    echo $flagcount;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try initializing $flagcount inside the loop.

Like this:

```
foreach( $rows as $result ) {

    $flagcount = 0;
    ...
```

Comment: I like that idea, I was hopefuly that could work but it doesn't I'm afraid. 

If I am setting $flagcount = 0; then immediately under it setting $flagcount = $result['flagnum']; then won't that just override anyway?

Comment: Yes, but the point is that it will NOT override it if the inner loop below never happens due to no results in the query. If you don't initialize it, then the next time the loop runs, it will use the value from the previous loop.

Comment: Works! I didn't know you meant the outer loop, I never thought of that. Thanks for working this out for me! I find loops a headspin.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Can you mark my answer as the solution so this will be resolved? Thanks!